# Is there an equivalent to jQuery.floatThead for row headers?

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table that is shaped kind of like an Excel grid (aka with headers for both rows and columns) and I want the headers for both axis to always stay visible, but still aligned.

I have found [jQuery.floatThead](http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/), but it only works for the Thead, which can only be at the top of the table.

Is there a way to reproduce the same effect as floatThead but for row headers?